# In edit mode scaling, moving and any other manipulation is done via increments

Tags: modeling

Basically, the functions of ctrl have switched with the basic controls. If I want to have smooth scaling, I now need to press ctrl. I don't know what I have toggled , but I'd rather not reload an entirely new project and copy over the obj file.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have turned snapping on. Press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> to toggle it off.